# How can I modify all values that match a condition inside a json array?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have a table which has a `JSON` column called *people* like this:

| Id | people |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[{ "id": 6 }, { "id": 5 }, { "id": 3 }]` |
| 2 | `[{ "id": 2 }, { "id": 3 }, { "id": 1 }]` |

...and I need to update the *people* column and put a `0` in the path `$[*].id` where `id = 3`, so after executing the query, the table should end like this:

| Id | people |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[{ "id": 6 }, { "id": 5 }, { "id": 0 }]` |
| 2 | `[{ "id": 2 }, { "id": 0 }, { "id": 1 }]` |

There may be more than one match per row.

Honestly, I didn´t tried any query since I cannot figure out how can I loop inside a field, but my idea was something like this:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
    SET people = JSON_SET(people, '$[*].id', 0)

WHERE /* ...something should go here */
```

---

This is my version

```sql
SELECT VERSION()

+-----------------+
|    version()    |
+-----------------+
| 10.4.22-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `id` values in `people` are unique, you can use a combination of [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_search/) and [`JSON_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_replace/) to change the values:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET people = JSON_REPLACE(people, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(people, 'one', 3)), 0)
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(people, 'one', 3) IS NOT NULL
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause is necessary to prevent the query replacing values with `NULL` when the value is not found due to `JSON_SEARCH` returning `NULL` (which then causes `JSON_REPLACE` to return `NULL` as well).

If the `id` values are not unique, you will have to rely on string replacement, preferably using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) to deal with possible differences in spacing in the values (and also avoiding replacing `3` in (for example) `23` or `34`:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET people = REGEXP_REPLACE(people, '("id"\\s*:\\s*)2\\b', '\\14')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=0aebbef9fa57f5cb0921a1d96ec283b5)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), MySQL stores JSON-format strings in a string column, for this reason you can either use the `JSON_SET` function or any string function.

For your specific task, applying the `REPLACE` string function may suit your case:

```
UPDATE 
    mytable
SET 
    people = REPLACE(people, CONCAT('"id": ', 3, ' '), CONCAT('"id": ',0, ' '))
WHERE 
    ....;
```